# Add empty rows to python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pd.dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
key_value    a      date      b
value_01     1   03/17/2018   10
value_01     2   03/18/2018   12
value_01     3   03/19/2018   13
value_02     1   04/01/2018   24
value_02     2   04/02/2018   27
value_02     3   04/03/2018   33
value_03     1   03/17/2018   13
value_03     2   03/18/2018   17
value_03     3   03/19/2018   22
```

So now based on the key_value,
I want to add say `n`(3 for now) amount of **Empty Rows** at the end of each key segment, so it should look something like this:

```
key_value    a      date      b
value_01     1   03/17/2018   10
value_01     2   03/18/2018   12
value_01     3   03/19/2018   13
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
value_02     1   04/01/2018   24
value_02     2   04/02/2018   27
value_02     3   04/03/2018   33
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
value_03     1   03/17/2018   13
value_03     2   03/18/2018   17
value_03     3   03/19/2018   22
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
NaN         NaN     NaN       NaN
```

I have tried thinking of a way using `grouby` based on `lease`, but couldn't figure out how to do it.
Thank you for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:
First find the index of the rows where the values change, and then from the bottom insert the`NaN`.

```
l = df.index[(df.key_value != df.key_value.shift(-1)) == True].tolist()
a = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
for i in reversed([x+1 for x in l]):
    for j in range(3):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, i, values=a, axis=0))
df.columns = ['key_value','a', 'date', 'b']
```

Output:

```
   key_value    a      date      b
0   value_01    1  03/17/2018   10
1   value_01    2  03/18/2018   12
2   value_01    3  03/19/2018   13
3        NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
4        NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
5        NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
6   value_02    1  04/01/2018   24
7   value_02    2  04/02/2018   27
8   value_02    3  04/03/2018   33
9        NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
10       NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
11       NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
12  value_03    1  03/17/2018   13
13  value_03    2  03/18/2018   17
14  value_03    3  03/19/2018   22
15       NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
16       NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
17       NaN  NaN         NaN  NaN
```

Comment: It works. Is there any way I could also ffill the key_value in those 3 empty rows.

Comment: Try with `df['key_value']=df['key_value'].ffill()`

Comment: That worked, just one last question if it's possible is there a way to increment the date's for those 3 columns too, I figured out a way to do column`a`

Comment: Right now i cannot try on pc, but i guess you should try something like `ffill` with `df['date']) + timedelta(days=1))`